# Compute an orthogonal matrix $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{3\text{x}3}$ and a matrix $R \in \mathbb{R}^{3\text{x}3}$ such that $A=QR$

Tags: matrices

Can anyone help me with this?

Let $A=\begin{bmatrix}10&1&0\\3&10&4\\4&1&3\end{bmatrix}$

of the form

$R=\begin{bmatrix}0&0&r_{13}\\0&r_{22}&r_{23}\\r_{31}&r_{32}&r_{33}\end{bmatrix}, \text{where} \   r_{13}>0, r_{23}<0,r_{31}>0,$

such that $A=QR$.

My question is:
$QR$ factorization is used to get an upper triangular $R$, but do I still use $QR$ for this question?

Comment: Better to write your problem here not just upload picture of it. Also can not read the problem from your photo

Answer (score 1):

Let $U=\pmatrix{0&0&1\\ 0&-1&0\\ 1&0&0}$. What class of matrices does $QU$ belong to? What is $UR$?